# Is this roof design with rafters, gussets and ties correct?

Tags: roof

The width is 16' so each side is a 2x6x10' board. The gussets will be plywood and the ties will be simple 2x4s. My questions are:

Is this design okay, it's hard to find examples of gussets used like this as most people use ridge boards.
Is it okay to just nail/screw the ties to the sides? When I see this done they often use plywood again to hold the ties to the rafters.

[image]

Comment: You may not need all the ties if you have ceiling rafters below the 2 runs of ties. If that is the case, and your local snow loads don't demand something stronger you could remove 1 tie and set the other one mid span of the rafters. If needed for the way I see the framing oriented, you may need to run strap ties from the ceiling joists to the rafters, since the ceiling joists are not tied to the rafters already.

Comment: usually the rafters attach to the side of the ceiling joists instead of passing above them